# GET country id from country name in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures

i have a list of countries with id i want to pull the country id of a specific country name

```
 export const country_list_with_id = [
        {
            id: 1,
            code: "AF",
            name: "Afghanistan"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            code: "AL",
            name: "Albania"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            code: "DZ",
            name: "Algeria"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            code: "DS",
            name: "American Samoa"
        },
    ...
```

if have country name like

```
countryname = algeria
```

is there a function to help me easily retrieve its country id

```
getcountryid(countryname){
return id 
}
```

I Found a solution

```
   getcountryid(countryname){
   country_list_with_id.map(res=>{
    if(res.name === country name){
       return res.id
        }
       });
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do something like that:

```
country_list_with_id.find(country=> country.name.toLowerCase() === countryname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function like this, supposing you already saved your data in an Array of Objects :

```
myResponse = [];

function(country) = {
 var id=0;
 this.myResponse.forEach((res) => {
     if (res.countryname.toLowerCase() === country) {
      id = res.id;
     }
  }
}
```

Or using find instead :

```
var countryName = "algeria";
var found = this.myResponse.find((res) => {
  return countryName === res.countryName.toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: a lile help here please 
i used .

Comment: getCountryID(countryName) {
  const countryID = country_list_with_id.forEach(res => {
   if (res.name.toLowerCase() === countryName) {
    return res.id;
    console.log("res.id= ", res.id);
   }
  });
  console.log("countryID is", countryID);
 }

Comment: but countryID is alwways undefined how should i return it